# Python/numpy: retrieve the array index of an element relative to the result of a function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I hope the title makes sense, I don't know how to put it exactly...

I have two 1-dimensional arrays (V and C) with an equal number of items inside. I need to obtain the maximum value of their product (Wmax), which I've achieved with this:

```
Wmax = numpy.amax(V*C)
```

However, I also need to extract the actual values of V and C that lead to Wmax. The idea then is to retrieve the array index of either V or C (they are the same anyway) and then read the value of both V and C at that index. One way that I've thought about to retrieve this index is to create a W array where each element is the product of each element of V and C, run numpy.amax on W instead of V*C and then find the index of Wmax inside W.

However, I wonder: is there a way to obtain this index without creating the new variable W? Would this different method be more or less efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do is to use [np.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) like that:

```
import numpy as np

C = np.array([0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5])
V = np.array([0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1])

indx = np.argmax(C*V)

print(f"index of the max value:{indx}")
print(f"C's value:{C[indx]}")
print(f"V's value:{V[indx]}")
```

> ```
> # output
>
>
> index of the max value:3
> C's value:3
> V's value:4
> ```